# WCF in UWP: should I explicitly call the OpenAsync() of the service client(proxy)?

Tags: wcf, uwp

I'm developing a UWP client project which need to consume some services of a WCF server. I uses the "add service reference" tool of Visual Studio to auto generate service clients(proxies). The binding type is `NetTcpBinding`. Below is some code snippet which create the service client:

```
    NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();

    tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
    tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
    tcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

    MainServiceClient = new MainServiceClient(tcpBinding, new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8773/MyWCF/MainService/tcp"));
```

The question is do I need to call `OpenAsync()` method of MainServiceClient? It seems the service client can be auto opened when it is first called. But I read from this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wenlong/2007/10/25/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared/) that auto-opened service client would have some performance penalty. The article was written in 2007. I just wonder if this mechanism have changed today, especially in UWP project. Can anyone share more light on this topic? Thanks!

Comment: No you do not have to call `OpenAsync()` method. You could get  the client and call the async method directly, the framework will handle the rest. However, as far as I know `Transport ` security mode of NetTcpBinding is currently not supported by uwp.

Comment: Thanks! But this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wenlong/2007/10/25/best-practice-always-open-wcf-client-proxy-explicitly-when-it-is-shared/) said that not explicitly calling `Open()` method will have some performance penalty. Does this changed in UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain this case, you should know three ways to do WCF instance management. `WCF` has provided three ways by which you can control WCF service instances:Per call, Per session, Single instance.

> When we configure a WCF service as per call, new service instances are created for every method call you make via a WCF proxy client.
>
> Very often we need to maintain state between method calls or for a particular session. For those kinds of scenarios, we will need to configure the service per session. In per session, only one instance of a WCF service object is created for a session interaction.
>
> Often we would like to create one global WCF instance for all WCF clients. To create a single instance of a WCF service, we need to configure the WCF service as Single instance mode.

And there are three ways by which you can handle concurrency for each service instance in `WCF` :single, multiple, and reentrant.

> Single: A single request has access to the WCF service object at a given moment of time. So only one request will be processed at any given moment of time. The other requests have to wait until the request processed by the WCF service is completed.
>
> Multiple: In this scenario, multiple requests can be handled by the WCF service object at any given moment of time. In other words, requests are processed at the same time by spawning multiple threads on the WCF server object. So you have great throughput here but you need to ensure concurrency issues related to WCF server objects.
>
> Reentrant: A single request thread has access to the WCF service object, but the thread can exit the WCF service to call another WCF service or can also call a WCF client through callback and reenter without deadlock.

In "Instance mode = Per Session and Concurrency = Single" combination, one WCF service instance is created for every WCF client session because the WCF instance mode is set to per session. All the method are executed in a sequential manner one by one. In other words, only one thread is available for all method calls for a particular service instance.

For the above scenario, you should always open WCF client proxy explicitly before you are making any calls. Because it will maintain service state between method calls and obtain high performance.

For more detail you could refer to ["WCF Concurrency (Single, Multiple, and Reentrant) and Throttling"](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and) and ["Three ways to do WCF instance management"](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per).

Comment: Thanks! Clear explanation!. And the two links are very helpful.